# Customizing magento advance search using custom form

Tags: php, forms, magento

I want to use the Magento advance search functionality using my custom form. I have created a static block that has a custom form and copied and pasted the form acion="getSearchPostUrl() ?>" to POST it in advance search. The result was 404 not found because the form was empty?

This is the custom form

```
<form id="prod-selector" action="&lt;?php echo $this-&gt;getSearchPostUrl() ?&gt;" method="POST">
    <div class="input-wrapper">
<h3>Drilling Brand</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input class="input-text validate-one-required-by-name" type="radio" value="bosch" name="torque-action" />
                <label for="">Bosch</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input class="input-text validate-one-required-by-name" type="radio" value="AEG" name="torque-action" />
                <label for="">AEG</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
<h3>Power</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><label for="">Enter Your Torque Required:</label></li>
            <li><input class="input-text validate-no-html-tags validate-alphanum-with-spaces" type="text" placeholder="Torque Required" name="torque-required" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
<h3>Metric unit</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input class="input-text validate-one-required-by-name" type="radio" value="torque tools" name="torque-action" />
                <label for="">ft. lbs.</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                    <input class="input-text validate-one-required-by-name" type="radio" value="calibration" name="torque-action" />
                    <label for="">N.m</label></li>
                <li>
                <input class="input-text validate-one-required-by-name" type="radio" value="torque tools" name="torque-action" />
                <label for="">Kgf.m</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrapper input-submit">
        <input id="hideit" style="display: none !important;" type="text" value="" name="hideit" />
        <button class="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have three attribute brand Bosch, AEG and Hitachi but Hitachi will be temporarily not available in the advance search. I also have Three metric unit ft. lbs, N.m, and Kgf.m that has individual values. The input field will accept only numeric.

The user will select which brand, input what force they need and choose what specific metric unit they are looking.

How do I customize the advance search for me to achieve the exact search result?

Thanks